# How to shorten Odata query string?

Tags: c#, odata

I have a method that queries an api using policy numbers. I found that the character limit for a query string is just over 2k. Here is my method that sends the query. How can I ensure or shorten the string so that it never goes above the character limit?

```
 public void BuildPolicyQuery()
        {
            if (!PolicyNumbers.IsAny()) return;
            //if (PolicyNumbers == null || PolicyNumbers.Count() == 0) return;
            QueryForWebServices = "Policy?$filter=PolicyNumber eq '" + PolicyNumbers.First() + "'";
            if (PolicyNumbers.Count() == 1) return;
            foreach (var p in PolicyNumbers.Skip(1))
            {
                QueryForWebServices += " or PolicyNumber eq '" + p + "'";
            }
        }
```

Comment: How can you be sure that the policy numbers alone won't add up to more than 2K characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can modify the service, then you could define an action on the Policy route and pass the policy numbers in the action payload. For example:

```
POST /Policy/SomeNamespace.GetSubsetByPolicyNumber
{ "PolicyNumbers": [ 123, 456, ... ] }
```

You'd want an action rather than a function because the former uses POST and takes a payload (content body) while the latter uses GET with parameters in the URI.

[Actions and Functions in OData v4 Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/odata-actions-and-functions)

Comment: Thanks, yes i realized that the error occurred when the string was built and not when it was sent. I realized that when i tried to use $Top to see where that would get me. Thanks for your help!